# How to tweak lucene maxClauseCount from Neo4j?

Tags: java, performance, lucene, neo4j, cypher

Following is our cypher for a find by ID kind of service:

```
START n=node:PATIENTS('MEMBER_PLAN_ID:(1 2)') return n
```

Where 1 2 are the ids passed. When we pass around 2000 ids following error occurs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'MEMBER_PLAN_ID:(1 2)': too many boolean clauses
        at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.IndexType.query(IndexType.java:304)
        at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:227)
        at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:238)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.GDSBackedQueryContext$$anon$1.indexQuery(GDSBackedQueryContext.scala:87)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$2.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:83)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$2.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:81)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:36)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:35)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.__AW_hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ClosingIterator.scala:36)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterator.scala:86)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.hasNext(ClosingIterator.scala:35)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:29)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult$$anon$1.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:73)
        at net.ahm.graph.dao.PatientDAO.__AW_findPatients(PatientDAO.java:376)


Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'MEMBER_PLAN_ID:(1 2)': too many boolean clauses
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:221)
        at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.IndexType.query(IndexType.java:300)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024
        at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.add(BooleanQuery.java:136)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.getBooleanQuery(QueryParser.java:958)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.getBooleanQuery(QueryParser.java:933)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1281)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1323)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1245)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1234)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:206)
        ... 39 more
```

We see this in the stack trace: **maxClauseCount is set to 1024**

Is there a way to configure this limit from Neo4j while using Cypher?

Comment: It is probably prohibitive. What is your use-case?

Comment: An external system elects a bunch of patients based on rules. Then it queries certain info about these patients from neo4j all in 1 roundtrip.

Comment: It's more prohibitive if you're not using Java-based Cypher, I think.

Comment: I am new to Neo4j. Only requirement i have is to fetch the info for multiple patients in 1 roundtrip. We had a IN sql in the legacy Oracle service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

However, if i add this line to our service, things work fine:

```
BooleanQuery.setMaxClauseCount(20000);
```

We did some load tests where 1000 concurrent users hit the service with 10,000 ids each. Not seeing service crash / any unexpected performance problems afterwards.

Comment: You might run into other problems, going higher, but if 3000 is good enough for all of your use cases, then you're probably ok. Can your patient rules give you an unlimited bunch of patients?

Comment: If the entire graph is in memory, i.e. we have a large enough heap... Can lucene still blow up?

Comment: I think you're paving your own path here--at least I've never tried that. :)

Comment: I have a bad feeling too :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this (untested):

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.lucene.maxClauseCount", "3000");
```

Comment: It did not work :( We are using Neo 1.9.3 which uses Lucene 3.6.2

Comment: Good to know. I'll leave it there for posterity.